Constructing equilateral triangle with a vertex on approximately lattice points
I know the fact that equilateral triangles can never have their vertices on lattice points.
Suppose I set two of its vertices on lattice points, then the third vertex must not be on any lattice point.
But it can be near to it.
My question is, can we find the third vertex very near to a lattice point? Is there a nice algorithm to do this?
I started as follows:
Let two lattice vertices are $(0,0)$ and $(a,b)$. Then the third vertex can be found using Euler's formula, which comes out to be $\left(\dfrac{a-b\sqrt 3}{2},\dfrac{a\sqrt 3 +b}{2}\right)$.
Can this 3rd vertex be near to a lattice point? If so, how exactly?(I mean, what's the condition?)
I found this nice example using trial and error in Geogebra.
The three vertices I picked are $(0,0), (7,4)$ and $(0.0358983848622,8.0621778264911),$ which is very near to $(0,8)$. The distance or the difference between them is $0.0717967...$ units, which is a very nice approximation within $0.1$ error.
Can we improve this? Can we somehow find the three vertices so that the third vertex is near to a lattice point within very low error, like $0.001$ or maybe less?
We can generalise this by saying that when is the distance of the third vertex from the lattice point nearest to it is within a distance of $1/n$ (when $n\rightarrow \infty$)?
I think this is interesting as a problem by itself and very suited to this site. Any help will be acknowledged.
Thanks in advance!

You might want to compare the error with the size of the triangle as otherwise you can just get closer with bigger triangles, such as $(0,0)$, $(101687054,0)$, $(50843527, 88063572.0000000170\ldots)$

By Minkowski's theorem, for every $\epsilon>0$ one can find a lattice point $(n,m)$ inside a tubular $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the ray forming a 60-degree angle with the positive $x$-axis.  Then the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(a,b)$, and $(0,2a)$ is what you are looking for.  By making $\epsilon$ sufficiently small one can make the error as small as desired.

Thanks for your time, but I'm sorry to say that I didn't quite understand what you are trying to say. Maybe this concept(Minkowski's theorem) is out of my level of understanding. Can you please explain this in simple terms?(if possible)

Take a very thin centrally symmetric rectangle around the 60-degree ray.  If the rectangle is long enough, it will have sufficient area to apply Minkowski's theorem (since the rectangle is convex).  This produces a lattice point inside the rectangle, which is therefore as close as one needs to the 60-degree line, giving the desired approximation.

We can generate constructions with two vertices on lattice points and the third vertex arbitrarily close to one using the continued fraction representation for $\sqrt3$.
We begin by rendering the exact coordinates for an equilateral triangle as follows:
$A=(0,0),B=(2,0),C=(1,\sqrt3)=(1,[1,\overline{1,2}])$
where $[1,\overline{1,2}]$ is the continued fraction form for $\sqrt3$. We get a rational approximation for $\sqrt3$ by truncating the infinite, periodic continued fraction; the exact square root lies between any truncation and the "augmented" truncation obtained by adding $1$ to the final coefficient in the truncation.
For example, suppose we truncate the continued fraction to
$[1,1,2,1,2] =19/11.$
The augmented truncation is obtained by adding $1$ to the final coefficient $2$ in the truncation:
$[1,1,2,1,3] =26/15=19/11+1/165.$
Using the $19/11$ approxination we multiply all the coordinates given above by $11$ to get integer values, thus we have the approxinate equilateral triangle
$A=(0,0),B=(22,0),C=(11,19)$
with the true equilateral triangle having $C$ above $(11,19)$ (because $26/15>19/11$) by an amount not exceeding $11/165=1/15$. Using more terms from the continued fraction would give a larger triangle but an absolutely closer approximation for vertex $C$.
We may examine precisely how close the approximation is as a function of the number of continued fraction coefgicients $n$ in our truncated approximation. Let $p/q$ be the truncated continued fraction and $p'/q'$ be the augmented truncation as defined above, woth $p$ prine to $q$ and $p'$ prime to $q'$ and all these variables positive. Thus with $n=5$ for the $\sqrt3$ continued fraction we have $p=19,q=11,p'=26,q'=15$ as in the above example. We then have (for any continued fractiin input) $p'q-pq'=(-1)^{n+1}$ and the value of the complete infinite continued fraction lies between $p/q$ and $p'/q'$, and we have the following error bound for the slope:
$|\sqrt3-(p/q)|\le|(p'q-pq')/qq'|=1/qq'.$
To get tge error in the $y$ coordinate when we place the vertex $C$ at $q,p$ using $p/q$ as the approximation for $\sqrt3$, we multiply the slope error $\le(1/qq')$ by the $x$- coordinate $q$. This gives $1/q'$ as the macimum possible error, which is the $1/15$ figure we found for the $n=5$ truncation calculated above. Since $q'$ increases without bound as we allow more terms in the continued fraction, we can approach the lattuce point arbitrarily closely with this method.

This gives an estimate for the slope, but additional estimates are needed to establish that the point thus obtained will indeed be close to the 60-degree ray.

I do not understand. I combine the slope estimate with putting tge third vertex on the perpendicular bisector of the opposing side. Is this not sufficient to guarantee thatthe tgird vertex is rendered close its true location?

Perhaps it does, but you have not provided the necessary estimates.  Approximating $\sqrt3$ is fine, but a priori this means only that the slope will be close to 60 degrees.  Additional estimates are needed to ensure that the point will actually be close to the 60-degree line.  I am not saying that continued fractions don't give such a consequence, but this needs to be argued.

@MikhailKatz will my edit work?

To solve this problem, we need rational approximations of $\sqrt3$. These can be obtained from the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt3$, but where does that continued fraction come from?
Let $p/q$ be an approximation of $\sqrt3$. Then
$$p^2-3q^2=d$$
for some integer $d$, with $|d|$ as small as possible.
Of course, $d\ne0$ because $\sqrt3$ is irrational. However, it was suspected since antiquity that there is always a solution for the integer equation $p^2-nq^2=1$ for any non-square $n$. Several prominent Indian mathematicians did important work on this and related equations, many centuries ago. This equation is now known as Pell's equation, and Lagrange proved that it always has a solution, and in fact it always has an infinite number of  $(p, q)$ solution pairs for any non-square $n$.
It can be tricky to find solutions to Pell's equation, but fortunately, when $n$ differs from a perfect square by 1 or 2 it's easy to find the smallest solution. For $n=3$, we have
$$2^2-3\cdot1^2=1$$
Now $2$ is not a great approximation of $\sqrt3$, but it's easy to generate other solutions. We write the equation as
$$p^2-(\sqrt3 q)^2=1$$
That's a difference of two squares, so we can factorize it:
$$(p+\sqrt3 q)(p-\sqrt3 q)=1$$
Now raise both sides to any integer power $k$:
$$(p+\sqrt3 q)^k(p-\sqrt3 q)^k=1$$
Those factors can always be written in the form
$p_k\pm\sqrt3 q_k$ for some integers $p_k, q_k$.
Let
$$p_{k+1}+\sqrt3 q_{k+1}=(p_k+\sqrt3 q_k)(2+\sqrt3)$$
Then
$$p_{k+1}+\sqrt3 q_{k+1}=(2p_k+3q_k) + \sqrt3(p_k+2q_k)$$
Equating coefficients, we get
$$p_{k+1}=2p_k+3q_k$$
and
$$q_{k+1}=p_k+2q_k$$

Here are some solution pairs.
\begin{array}{r}
p & q\\
\hline
2 & 1\\
7 & 4\\
26 & 15\\
97 & 56\\
362 & 209\\
1351 & 780\\
5042 & 2911\\
18817 & 10864\\
70226 & 40545\\
262087 & 151316\\
978122 & 564719\\
3650401 & 2107560\\
\end{array}
Note that if $p/q \approx \sqrt3$, then $3q/p$ is another approximation with similar error. Eg, $$\left(\frac74\right)^2=3+\frac{1}{16}$$
and
$$\left(\frac{12}{7}\right)^2=3-\frac{3}{49}$$

Here's a small Python script to generate the $(p, q)$ pairs.

Observation: we get only the approximants exceedimg the square root of 3. Thus only half of them.

@Oscar True, but the approximants $3q/p$ are under $\sqrt3$. For some $n$, eg 2, we get solutions for $p^2-nq^2=-1$, which give alternating approximations under and over $\sqrt n$.

This gives an estimate for the slope, but additional estimates are needed to establish that the point thus obtained will indeed be close to the 60-degree ray.

We can use a variant of the Euclidean Algorithm to prove that given any real number $\epsilon >0$ and irrational number $x$, there is some $n$ such that $nx$ is within $\epsilon$ of an integer.
Given some real number $x$, I'll be using $\%1$ to represent amount by which $x$ is more than the next smaller integer. For instance, $\pi \%1$ is approximately $0.1415$.
Let's start with $a_1$ and $a_2$ such that $(a_1\sqrt 3)\%1 > (a_2 \sqrt 3 )\%1$. Now let's divide $(a_1\sqrt 3)\%1$ by $(a_2\sqrt 3)\%1$. We can express the result in terms of some integer $n$ and remainder $r$:
$(a_1\sqrt 3)\%1=n[(a_2\sqrt 3)\%1]+r$
or
$r = (a_1\sqrt 3)\%1-n[(a_2\sqrt 3)\%1] = [(a_1-na_2) \sqrt 3)]\%1$.
Now, if $(a_2\sqrt 3)\%1$ is more than one half of $(a_1\sqrt 3)\%1$, then $n=1$, and we have less than one half of $(a_1 \sqrt 3)\%1$ left when we subtract $(a_2\sqrt 3)\%1$.
On the other hand, $r$ is less than $(a_2\sqrt 3)\%1$, so if $(a_2\sqrt 3)\%1$ is less than one half of $n(a_2\sqrt 3)\%1$, then $r$ is as well. This shows that $r$ is less than one half of $(a_1 \sqrt 30)\%1$.
So let's take $a_3$ to be $a_1-na_2$. We can now repeat this process with $a_2$ and $a_3$: divide whichever one is larger by the smaller one, take the remainder, and use that to get $a_4$. If we keep doing this, we get a sequence of positive numbers that is bounded above by an exponentially decreasing function. Therefore, the limit is zero.
An examples: let's start with $\sqrt 3 = 1.732$ and $2\sqrt 3 = 3.464$. We take the larger decimal part and divide by the smaller: $0.732/0.464$. This gets us $1$ with a remainder of  $0.268$. So we have $0.268 = 0.732-1*0.464$. Since we got $0.732$ by multiplying $\sqrt 3$ by $1$, and $0.464$ by multiplying by $2$, we take $1-1*2=-1$. This tells us that $-\sqrt 3$ is $0.268$ more than the next smaller integer. And indeed, $-\sqrt 3$ is $-1.732$, which is $0.268$ more than $-2$.
We can then divide $0.464$ by $0.268$, and we get $1$ remainder $0.196$. So we take $2-(-1)=3$. And indeed $3*\sqrt 3= 5.196$.
